# Tier 2 ICT dependent visa for the new born baby in UK

Tags: uk-visa

I am looking for a clarification in regards to visa (Tier 2 ICT dependent visa) for our baby.

Please note that I hold an Indian passport and currently working on Tier 2 ICT visa in UK (which is valid till Jan 2020). We are expecting our baby in Feb 2018. Hence this query is regarding visa for the new born baby.

As I have understood, we need to apply for the baby's Indian passport which is clear for me.

We are planning for a trip to India after obtaining Indian passport for the baby. However I am looking for clarifications for below queries please?

- Is it mandatory to apply for visa for baby to travel from UK to India on a short trip ?
- Can we apply for baby's visa after reaching India as my wife and baby are intended to stay in India for about 6 months before flying back to UK.

Thanks in advance for your response.

Answer (score 2):

- It is not mandatory for the child to have a visa to *leave* the UK.
- You can apply for the baby's visa from India, no problem except for perhaps time. However 6 months should be more than sufficient provided you meet all of the support requirements.

Comment: Glad to help. If you consider any answer useful, consider voting it up as this encourages participation.

Comment: Hello Ouflak. Hope you are doing well. In continuation to our previous discussions, I just got a small doubt with the same issue about the visa. I was reading Tier 2 ICT dependent visa requirements for baby born in UK in UK.GOV website which states as below:                                                                                                             Children born while you’re in the UK

If you have children while you’re in the UK, you can apply for permission for them to stay.

You must do this if you want to travel in and out of the UK with them.

Comment: This wording seems correct and identical to what I've posted. If you want to bring the child out of the UK (and you want them to reenter), you will have to apply for some kind of visa for them.at some point before the child returns. What was your question?